# Is it possible to configure linked server on read-only mode

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net, oracle10g

I have a SQL SERVER 2008 R2 on development environment that connect to production Oracle Server (10g) environment via Linked Server.

To ensure that I do not Write data to Oracle inadvertently, would it be possible to configure the linked server as read-only. If so How..

Comment: If there is a read only account configured in Oracle, you should be able to set up the linked server using this readonly credential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the permissions are on the Oracle side with the credentials used to connect. You'd limit permissions to read only there.

As soon as the linked server is visible in SQL Server people can use it like they would a table: but with no permissions on the SQL Server side as a linked server isn't a securable object.